# PHP sorting an array by mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, date, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I would like to sort using a date field from a MySQL database.

Here is a sample of the array which is named `news` in my class:

```
[48] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [type] => 3
        [updated] => 2010-04-17 13:54:42
    )

[49] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [type] => 3
        [updated] => 2010-04-17 13:57:21
    )
```

I want to sort by the `updated` field.

I have some code I have started but am unsure how to complete it and get it working.

```
class ProcessClass {
  // ....
  function sortNews($x)
  {
    usort($this->news, array("ProcessClass", "cmp")); //correct sort type?
  }

  function cmp($a, $b)
  {
    //  missing code
  }
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: why not to sort already in mysql?

Comment: Can not you sort in MySQL side ?

Comment: Sorry I should have said, the array is built from about 5 different SQL select queries, that differ in various circumstances so can not be joined.

Comment: You could still edit that into your question!  Thanks for asking on stack overflow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases, will be easier to add `ORDER BY updated` to the end of the SQL query, however if your data is coming from multiple sources and you need to resort in PHP, you can use [usort()](https://www.php.net/usort) to sort an array based on a user defined function.  To use a class function for comparison, the function **MUST** be static.  It can simply compare the `updated` value in the array using the function [strcmp()](https://www.php.net/strcmp) which happens to return exactly what you need to sort by a MySQL formatted date:

```
class ProcessClass {
  // this must be static
  static function sort_by_updated($a, $b)
  {
    return strcmp($a['updated'], $b['updated']);
  }
  
  function sortNews()
  {
    usort($this->news, array("ProcessClass", "sort_by_updated")); 
  }
```

If you want to reverse sort order, simply swap the comparison params: `return strcmp($b['updated'], $a['updated'])`

Comment: Agreed, get the database to sort, that's what databases are good for.

Comment: Sorry I should have said, the array is built from about 5 different SQL select queries, that differ in various circumstances so can not be joined.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting array of records/assoc_arrays by specified mysql datetime field and by order:

```
    function build_sorter($key, $dir='ASC') {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key, $dir) {
            $t1=strtotime(is_array($a)?$a[$key]:$a->$key);
            $t2=strtotime(is_array($b)?$b[$key]:$b->$key);
            if($t1==$t2) return 0;
            return (str_to_upper($dir)=='ASC'?($t1 < $t2):($t1 > $t2)) ? -1 : 1;
        };
    }


    // $sort - key or property name 
    // $dir - ASC/DESC sort order or empty
    usort($arr, build_sorter($sort, $dir));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use PHP sorting, you could go for a [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) implementation.

```
<?php
function mysql_datesort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a->date_field < $b->date_field) ? -1 : 1; //custom check here
}

$a = array(); //your PHP array here...

usort($a, "mysql_datesort");

?>
```